# Selenium button click is not working as expected on the page URL

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, css-selectors

I am trying to download a JSON file from web links by clicking on the download button, but the download button is not responding even when I am using the right ID or selector.

Below is my code and the website I am trying to extract data from.
The problem is from this line  `driver.find_element(By.ID, "exportResultsButton").click()`. I need help in fixing it. Thanks

No response yet.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

# Initialize the Chrome web driver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

# Navigate to the webpage
url = 'https://ntsb.gov/Pages/monthly.aspx'
driver.get(url)
driver.maximize_window()

# Find all elements matching your XPath selector
link_elements = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="NTSBContentArea"]//span//a')

links_list = set()
# Extract and print the links
for link_element in link_elements:
    link = link_element.get_attribute('href')
    links_list.add(link)

# Loop through the links and download JSON data
for link in links_list:
    driver.get(link)
    try:
        time.sleep(15)

        # Click the "Download Data (JSON)" button
        driver.find_element(By.ID, "exportResultsButton").click()

        # Retrieve and print or save the JSON data
        json_data = driver.page_source
        # Process or save the JSON data as needed
        print(json_data)

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error downloading data from {link}: {str(e)}")

# Close the browser
driver.quit()
```